# Closings and deletions can happen too quickly

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, deleted-posts

I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow and already have experience with getting both a question and an answer deleted.

I understand why [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214962/maximum-count-of-type-parameters) was closed, but the closing happened too fast. The first time I looked at my question after posting it, it was already closed; I didn't get the chance to respond.

The deletion of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397390/remove-from-listt-based-on-sub-string-match/9397573#9397573) was done by mistake. The deleter wrote that I should have deleted the answer by myself to avoid bothering the moderators. That was offensive, IMO.

I suggest implementing a time period, e.g. one day, during which questions cannot be closed. That way, authors would have the chance to explain the causes of their answers.

Comment: Are you referring to your *["Maximum Number of Type Parameters a Human Being can Understand"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214962)* question, or your three deleted answers on [this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397390)

Comment: A time limit on deleting new questions might be reasonable, for some of the reasons why it might be deleted (if it's a clear spam post, or something, obviously would be excluded), but poor questions should be closed ASAP, and can be opened upon improvement.

Comment: Please note, that *everything* happens fast on Stack Overflow. Answer happen fast--sometimes unbelievably so---on good questions. One of our on-going problems with new users is that they figure it will be good enough to check back in a few hours to see if there have been any comments (a perfectly reasonable behavior on most on-line forums); here resulting in frustration from the user base that they won't answer questions or fix problems.

Comment: The crucial point is that questions are *closed* quickly, but not *deleted* for a while. That prevents an influx of answers while the person who asked the question has a chance to improve it and make it constructive/on-topic/whatever. Then, it can be re-opened and there won't be a flood of useless answers left in the meantime. If you *don't* fix the question while it's closed, it will eventually get deleted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes that are my related issues.

Comment: And again frustration: 15 down votes for my serious question. I have waited several days before I wrote it because I was not sure whether meta is the right place and whether this question would also been deleted. Ok I could just leave StackOverflow but it is a great and very useful side - besides some issues.

Comment: Votes are different on Meta: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences for most people voting, it probably simply meant "I disagree with this suggestion"

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello thanks, I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Closing *needs* to be swift - Stack Overflow gets 4,000 new questions a day, most of them crap (I do not necessarily mean your question; I haven't seen it). Not being able to close crap straight away would create chaos.

But I agree a closed question doesn't need to be *deleted* straight away, and telling an OP to delete to spare the mods' time is pretty offensive if the question was asked in good faith. Consider editing and undeleting your question - it might gain enough reopen votes to go back into business.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, the "telling an OP to delete" portion was in reference to an *answer* (one of three posted to a question). I suspect brgerner could've used some advice on how to edit.